# How to check ngform is valid or not

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-form

I am using ng-repeat for dynamically creating controls as below

```
<div ng-form="mainform" ng-repeat="usr in users">
    <userdirective ng-form="innerform_idx_{{$index}}></userdirective>
</div>
```

in my controller i want to check if  inner forms are valid or not.
I tried below , but it is not working

```
for(i=0;i<users.length;i++)
{
 var innerformName="innerform_idx_"+i;
  if( $scope.mainform.innerformName.$valid)
   {
    // throwing undefined error.
   }
}
```

Please suggest how can i dynamically check validity of inner form.

Thanks,

Comment: Try `$scope.mainform[innerformName].$valid`

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, generating a dynamic name for an inner form doesn't work well. However, angular seems to be perfectly fine with having multiple inner forms with the same (static) name.

For validating *a single* inner form in the controller, you can pass the inner forms validity as a parameter from the view to the controller.

It's also important to know that the parent form will be invalid if any of the child forms is invalid. This can be used for validating *all* inner forms at the same time.

Code snippet to demonstrate:

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('myctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.users = ['u1', 'u2', 'u3'];
  $scope.validateForm = function(form) {
    alert('form is valid: ' + form.$valid);
  }
});
```

```css
.userform {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">
  <div ng-form="parentform">
    <div class="userform" ng-repeat="user in users" ng-form="innerform">
      <div>Username (maximum 5 characters): {{user}}</div>
      <input ng-maxlength="5" ng-model="user" />
      <div ng-class="{'invalid': !innerform.$valid}">inner form is valid: {{innerform.$valid}}</div>
      <button ng-click="validateForm(innerform)">Check my validy in the controller</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-class="{'invalid': !parentform.$valid}">Parent form is valid: {{parentform.$valid}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```